# How to call Jquery blur event from JS file while writing Qunit test case

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I have custom **search.JS** file and contents in JS file as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#number_c").blur(function(){
        toggle($("#number_c"),[$("#number_a"),$("#number_b")]);       
    });

    function toggle(input1, inputs) {

       if (input1.val() != '' ) {

         for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
            input = inputs[i];
            input.val('');
            input.prop("disabled",true);
        }
     } else {
       for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
           input = inputs[i];
           input.removeAttr("disabled");
       }
    }
  }

});
```

**HTML** file have below entry:

```
    <label for="number_a">Number 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="number_a"><br>
    <label for="number_b">Number 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="number_b"><br>
    <label for="number_c">Number 3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="number_c"><br>
```

I need to write Qunit test case to call blur method. I tried to trigger blur event in Qunit test case JS file but not able to call search.js blur event.Please suggest me how I can write.Thanks in advance.

I tried to put toggle function outside of $(document).ready function in search.js file and written below Qunit test. This test return as expected and able to call toggle function.

```
QUnit.test("Verify number_b disabled field", function(assert) { $('#number_c').val('201');  
toggle($("#number_c"),[$("#number_a"),$("#number_b")]); 
//$('#result').focus(); 
assert.equal($('#number_b').prop("disabled"), true, 'expected number_b fields needs to be disabled'); });
```

But, I am trying to call blur event of search.js file from my search_test.js file. I tried to trigger using **$('#number_c').trigger('blur');** in my search_test.js file but this not worked.

Comment: What have you tried in the test so far? Show us what you have written and we can try to help.

Comment: Hi @jakerella, I added in my question section. Please suggest what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the `toggle()` function outside of the source code file because you have wrapped it in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (which is a good thing). The only way you can test the source code as is is to [trigger a `blur` event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) from within your test. Try this:

```
QUnit.test("Verify number_b disabled field", function(assert) { 
  $('#number_c').val('201');  

  $('#number_c').trigger('blur');  // this line "fakes" a blue event

  assert.equal($('#number_b').prop("disabled"), true, 'expected number_b fields needs to be disabled'); });
});
```

Comment: Hi @jakerella, I also used exact same thing what you mentioned but not able to trigger blur event of search.js. I also used console.log to see control.

Comment: It's possible that this test is running _before_ your search.js code. If so, you would probably need to have some sort of "initialize" type of function in search.js which your test runs to kick things off